# Regular Expression - Not Matching Full Text/Replacing Other Parts

Tags: regex, replace, textpad

I have a quiz that looks similar to the following:

```
1: How old am I?
A: 8 days
B: 75
C: 100
D: 99correct
xxxxxxxxxxxx
2: What is your favorite color?
A: blue
B: greencorrect
C: red
D: blue
xxxxxxxxxxxx
```

In each case, the correct answer is marked by using the word correct at the end of the correct answer.

What I want to do is to take that correct answer and add it after the xxxxxxxxxxxx, so that it reads:

```
xxxxxxxxxxxx B: Green.
```

I am currently using the following regex within Textpad in order to find the correct answer

```
FIND:     ([A-D]:(?s).*correct(?s).*xxxxxxxxxxxx)
REPLACE:  \1xxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Unfortunately, it is not working as it is replacing the whole quiz with the whole quiz and then adding xxxxxxxxxxx

But the main question, is how do I replace text that is not actually specified as the 'find text'?

Thank you.

PS. Two answers seem to have missed this, so is probably my fault that this is not clarified:

It shouldn't be adding an extra xxxxxxxxxxxx before the answer, but copying the line eg. B: greencorrect after the final xxxxxxxxxxxx for that question.

Here is sample output for the above example:

```
1: How old am I?
A: 8 days
B: 75
C: 100
D: 99correct
xxxxxxxxxxxx D: 99
2: What is your favorite color?
A: blue
B: greencorrect
C: red
D: blue
xxxxxxxxxxxx B: green
```

Obviously, the correct answer could be A,B,C or D.

Comment: also pls put expected output pls and also what should it do with the copied one tho?

Comment: also pls put sample input

Comment: Try [this approach](https://regex101.com/r/ntZ57i/2), that is, look for `(?m)^([A-D]:.*?)correct$((?:\n.*)*?\nx{3,})` and replace with `\1\2 \1`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew now post it as an answer, it would be helpful

Comment: @GhostOps Did you test it in TextPad? Does it work there?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew i don't have textpad actually, i just saw `\1` in the code, so i thought it is something related to python regex, so i did it for python, and you can see it in the regex101 demo in my answer

Comment: I have put sample input and output above. Sorry for any confusion

Comment: Then https://regex101.com/r/yd6kmE/1 will do something similar, but with PCRE option at regex101.

Comment: The answer you wrote above is correct:
 (?m)^([A-D]:.*?)correct$((?:\n.*)*?\nx{3,}) and replace with \1\2 \1
Amazing! THank you.

Comment: Aha, so, `correct` word should be missing from the answer line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```py
(?m)^([A-D]:.*?)correct$((?:\n.*)*?\nx{3,})
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ntZ57i/2). The replacement pattern should be `\1\2 \1`.

*Details*:

- `(?m)` - a multiline inline modifier (might be redundant in a text editor)
- `^` - start of a line
- `([A-D]:.*?)` - Group 1: `A`, `B`, `C` or `D`, then a `:` and then any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `correct` - a `correct` word
- `((?:\n.*)*?\nx{3,})` - Group 2:

  - `(?:\n.*)*?` - zero or more lines, but as few as possible
  - `\n` - a newline char
  - `x{3,}` - three or more `x` chars.

Answer (score 0):

I've never worked with Textpad in particular, but in Sublime Text 3 you might want to do something like this:

```
FIND:      ^([A-D]:\s\S.*?)correct$
REPLACE:   xxxxxxxxxxxx $1.
```

It's going to turn your example into:

```
<...>
xxxxxxxxxxxx D: 99.
<...>
xxxxxxxxxxxx B: green.
<...>
```

Note that since I use `^` and `$` (the beginning and the end of a line), if your editor asks you to enable multi-line mode, try to enable it if this doesn't work for you with default mode.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Here's the problem though. It shouldn't be adding an extra xxxxxxxxxxxx before the answer, but copying the line eg. B: greencorrect after the final xxxxxxxxxxxx

Comment: I assume then that you described your task in a very poor way since I'm not the only person who misunderstand it

Answer (score 0):

Try this
Find: `([A-D]:[\w ]*correct)`
Replace: `xxxxxxxxxxxx \1`

Outputs:

```
1: How old am I?
A: 8 days
B: 75
C: 100
xxxxxxxxxxxx D: 99correct
xxxxxxxxxxxx
2: What is your favorite color?
A: blue
xxxxxxxxxxxx B: greencorrect
C: red
D: blue
xxxxxxxxxxxx
```

[**Regex101 Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/6oZVso/2)

Tell me if its not working for you...

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Here's the problem though. It shouldn't be adding an extra xxxxxxxxxxxx before the answer, but copying the line eg. B: greencorrect after the final xxxxxxxxxxxx